# How to give rewards to users

Tags: tokens, nft, tokenomics

I'm a crypto noob. We have an application in which users can create food recipies and other users can use them and thank them for.
Now we want to reward recepie creator based on the amount of "thanks" they got from other users (Suppose we issue some token on ethereum) and send these tokens to recepie creators.

Is there any Cryptocurrency-based solution to prevent fraud? We want to prevent recepie owners from generating wallets and thanking themselves!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could lead to problems like the one stated by the previous commentor such as bots or person creating random wallet addresses.

The rewards in DEFI are usually given out to Stakers. So, if you want such project where you reward thankers, I think a good architecture would be to create NFTs or some identifiers to stake/verify before actually giving out rewards.

Answer (score 1):

You can't stop a person from generating more wallets and using them to thank themselves. Rather, you can ask for other user data from them when they sign up on your platform, instead of just using their wallet address as an identifier.

for eg., make them link their discord/email or any other account/identifier as well. This is not a full-proof solution as one can have multiple email ids as well, but it's much more resilient than just having a wallet address as identifier.